# vue bind class if values equals false

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, boolean

I have this website, that gets some boolean values and stores them in an array where key = id and value = boolean.

E.g.

```
policiesActive[
"2"   => false,
"3"   => false]
```

I have a list-group with three items.

E.g.

```
.list-group
    a.list-group-item.list-group-item-action.flex-column.align-items-start(v-for='firewallPolicy in activeFirewall.policies', href='', @click.prevent='setPolicyActive(activeFirewall.id, firewallPolicy.id)', v-bind:class='{ active: policiesActive[firewallPolicy.id] }')
        .d-flex.w-100.justify-content-between
        h5.mb-1 {{firewallPolicy.name}}
        p.mb-1 {{firewallPolicy.description}}
```

Each list-group-item should be checked to be either active or not. The two first are checked against `policiesActive` and the third is true if both `policiesActive` values are false.

I can't figure how to check the last part where both values is false.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Most straightforward approach might be to use a method to compute the class. Here's a simplified version

```
<a
    v-for="(policy, index) in policies"
    class="list-group-item"
    :class="getItemClass(policy, index)"
    href="..."
>
    ...
</a>
```

Then

```
methods: {
    getItemClass(policy, index) {
        let itemClass = "";
        // ... whatever logic you want to calculate the classname
        return itemClass;
    }
}
```